# Progress Bar Resets when Flipping the Device

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I have a small problem, which is probably not the hardest to solve, I just couldn't find anything so far:

In my application I use a progress bar that is connected to a `CountDownTimer`. When I flip the device, the Progress Bar resets to 0 and the Timer doesn't which leads to the time being up while the bar is still somewhere in the middle. I use two different layout files for portrait/landscape, but the Progress Bar definition doesn't differ.

This is the java code:

```
mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(6000,50) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i + millisUntilFinished);
                i++;
                mProgressBar.setProgress(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                i++;
                mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time Up!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                if(counter < DBAdapter.NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS){
                    i=0;
                    newQuestion();
                }
                else endGame();
            }
        };
```

This the xml code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:max="120"
    android:progress="0"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that when a flip occurs you activity gets destroyed and gets re-created again. Hence the values in the local variables get lost.

To avaoid losing such values use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to store the progress value and retrieve it back.

Example,

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("PROGRESS VALUE", i);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    i = savedInstanceState.getInt("PROGRESS VALUE");
}
```

Yo can read more about this here,

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

You can learn more on this here.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VYlTgaAHTs&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=31

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XqHvJK9xn4&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=32

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LYhbQXu19U&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=33

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3NsvUX_Fwo&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=34

I hope this helped you!